# Can an infected DVD+RW affect a Linux PC?

Tags: mount, sudo, dvd, automount

Yesterday I started my laptop (using a sudoer user because I wanted to install one program) with an infected DVD + RW inside my laptop (it was recorded using aother computer that is infected and I guess it might be infected). The DVD was automatically mounted

As soon as I realized the DVD was mounted I unmount it and remove it from my laptop (No file in that DVD was opened), and then I reboot the laptop.

I guess that it is not possible to infect a Linux PC if you don't run any file as root (or using sudo) ,and I did not use that command before unmounting the DVD, but as I said I started my laptop using a sudoer user, and so I entered my sudo password when I logged in.

The questions are: Can I infect a Linux PC by accidentally automounting an infected DVD while I am registered as a sudoer user?, in case I wanted to check if the PC was infected,  which changes should I check? (I had a look at /var/logs/apt, /usr/bin and /usr/lib and no files were modified whle the DVD was mounted). When I entered the user password in the log in screen, was the DVD already monted, or the system mounts the DVD after log in?

Thanks.

PS: I know this question might seem a bit paranoid, but it has never been asked nor answered  so I think it is an interesting question to ask

Comment: Although all things are possible, it is unlikely. It depends on what the DVD is infected with.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible, but to be sure you can boot from a live CD and from there use `chkrootkit` and `clamav` to check for infections.

In general, **never log in as root!** Just don't. It's dangerous and completely unnecessary. Whatever you want to do, almost everything can be done via **`sudo`**. There's a reason you can't log in as root per default, and there's a reason that `sudo` exists.

Answer (score 1):

- **Don't worry**, for security reasons Linux systems doesn't support the Autorun feature and mounting a partition (like the [Joliet](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Joliet_%28file_system%29&oldid=589553948)
  ones) also *should not* execute any code if you didn't install specific
  daemons to do so, so you're relatively safe.
  Linux Ubuntu will be safe and secure as long as you keep it updated with the security updates and access the root privileges only with `sudo`.
- Remember that **Windows malware can't be executed in Linux**: you can use Ubuntu to detect and destroy any type of Windows malware, specially in mobile drivers.
- If you want to check for infected or not regular software use directly a [rootkit scanner](http://www.rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html) and the [ClamAV](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV) antivirus: the reason is that by checking manually you can be fooled to execute harmful code by a rootkit+trojan horse combination, if you are infected by Unix/Linux malware. Simply use the apposite softwares and let them do their job.

  Have a nice experience, please comment down here if you have any doubt and click the UP arrow if I'm of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows, which automatically thinks *'I'll run this, it will all be OK'*, Linux is generally less bad at that sort of thing - only really if you intentionally do something daft will anything bad really happen.

This depends also what was on the DVD, but even if it had a program that could quite happily infect the entire system, it would still need to be executed / told to run. Mounting the DVD would probably not be enough. Even then, programs such as [SELinux](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux), ClamAV should hopefully notify you of any problems.

But, there would be no harm in checking the system for security flaws or problems.